# Routing parameters ... Can I restrict routing to within country borders?

Tags: here-api

I've developed a route mapping tool using the Here mapping api. It's working fine with the minor exception of the occasional route that crosses into Canadian territory. Is there a routingParameter setting that can restrict the routing to stay within a country border?

Comment: Can you please confirm which API is being used in your use case ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such parameter, and I assume you can work around by listing all neighbor countries to the `excludeCountries` parameter.

There is a parameter to exclude countries. It takes a list of ISO 3166-1-alpha-3 country codes, like that

```
excludeCountries=BOL,PRY,URY
```

for more details you can check below source:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-calculate-route.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: HERE Support, I think Karl is loking for a solution for routing api, not maptile api